# Can't get this C language program related to strings to work

Tags: c, scanf

So I'm trying to build this program where the user inputs a value (character) and the program does a specific task depending on the value the user inserted, however I can't find what i'm doing wrong... please help somebody?

Here is the code (It's obviously not finished I'm just trying to make it work for the value of s at the moment.)

```
int d = 0;

do 
{
    char value;

    printf("Command list:\t \n\nCommand: \t Output: ");

    printf("\n \"A\"  \t Declare values of a list.\n \"O\"  \t Obtain the average value of the values in the list.\n");

    printf(" \"P\"  \t Print the values of the list.\n \"S\"  \t End program. \n");

    printf("Insert value: ");
    scanf(" %c", value);


    if (value == 'S' || value == 's')
    {
        d = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nInvalid Command.");
    }
}
while (d = 0);
```

Comment: `while (d == 0);` instead.  If that doesn't work, please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, change

```
scanf(" %c", value);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &value);
```

as `scanf()` needs the address of the variable in which it is going to store the scanned value.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
scanf(" %c", value);
```

to this

```
scanf(" %c", &value);
```

you need to pass a pointer to `scanf` so that it updates the value pointed to by the pointer

Answer (score 0):

You missed to put the `&` before the argument. You need to change

```
scanf(" %c", value);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &value);
             ^
             |
```